# How to block all hosts and only forward web traffic for a specific server

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a Web server (*Server A*) and a VPN server (*Server B*).

I want a setup such that when any device is connected to the VPN, the only site they'll be able to access is the webserver (*Server A*).

Every other host should be inaccessible to the user

How can I accomplish this with iptables?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried already? What research have you done so far? :)

Comment: I'm not really a server admin but i know it can be done with iptables. i did some research but iptables is really broad and confusing. right now i'm forwarding all traffic with nat 
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/24 -o eth0 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

I just don't know how to limit this to only a specific server and drop all other packets